# Server side validation not firing when JS Disabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to validate an ASP.NET BasicDatePicker Control at the server side when JS is disabled, but cannot seem to get the event to fire.

There is JS Validation (Using .NET Validators) but we are still receiving batches of searches using invalid dates. Which suggests to me that a spambot or other botnet is bypassing the JavaScript validation.
We have used FF addons to disable JavaScript to test whether the field is validated, but the postback event does not seem to fire.

Code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**ASP.NET ASPX PAGE**

```
<div align="center">
    {EXTRA MARKUP REMOVED}
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:words, Arrival_Date %>"></asp:Label>
    <BDP:DateRangeValidator ID="DateRangeValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="DateRangeValidator"
        ControlToValidate="datefrom" Text="**"></BDP:DateRangeValidator><BDP:IsDateValidator
            ID="IsDateValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="IsDateValidator" ControlToValidate="datefrom"
            Text="*"></BDP:IsDateValidator><br />
    <BDP:BDPLite ID="datefrom" runat="server" TextBoxColumns="12" />
    &nbsp;<hlp:popup ID="popup4" runat="server" contextid="hlp_arrivaldate" />
    {EXTRA MARKUP REMOVED}
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Font-Size="11px" Text="<%$ Resources:words, Search %>"
        UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <div style="padding-bottom: 5px">
        <asp:Label ID="serverErrorMessage" runat="server" Visible="false" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**BUTTON1_CLICK EVENT (DOES NOT SEEM TO FIRE)**

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'check for stuff in the date field
    If InStr(Me.datefrom.ToString, "http") > 0 Then Exit Sub
    If InStr(Me.datefrom.ToString, "//") > 0 Then Exit Sub
    If InStr(Me.txtPropertyLike.ToString, "http") > 0 Then Exit Sub
    If InStr(Me.txtPropertyLike.ToString, "//") > 0 Then Exit Sub

    'test the date, and exit if not valid
    Dim datetest As Date = CDate("01-Jan-2001")
    Try
        datetest = CDate(Me.datefrom.SelectedDate)
        If datetest < Today Or DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, Today, datetest) > 2 Then
            datetest = CDate("01-Jan-2001")
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
    If datetest = CDate("01-Jan-2001") Then
        serverErrorMessage.Text = "Date be within the next 2 calendar years."
        serverErrorMessage.Visible = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

I know it's probably something stupid. Just can't figure out what and as I already have no hair, there are none to pull out. :(

JGe

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding if you will use Page.IsValid it will solve your problem .

like

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
if (Page.IsValid)
   {
    // your code 
   } else {
   // some error message to user 
  }
```

For this property to return true, all validation server controls in the current validation group must validate successfully.

Let me know it it solve your problem. Happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks for responding,
This hasn't solved this issue, it appears that the Button1_Click event isn't firing so therefore not getting to the point of execution on your answer?